# Grails login.gsp not present

Tags: grails

I'm running grails 3 with the security plugin (entry from gradle file)

> compile group: 'org.grails.plugins', name: 'spring-security-core',
>   version: '3.2.3'

Then run:

```
s2-quickstart mydomain User Role
```

and now the security is being applied to the site.

Now I need to change the login.gsp page but it's not under views.

Must I run another command to generate it (and the controller)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your own login page by adding a file in your app under `grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp` - this will take precedence over the one in the plugin.

You can use `auth.gsp` from the plugin as a starting point for yours. It can be found here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/plugin/grails-app/views/login/auth.gsp

I'm not aware of any command that puts the views auth.gsp or denied.gsp in your app.

Answer (score 2):

First, We need to add Spring Security Core Plugin as a dependency:
`/build.gradle`

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1'`

Then,

There are two ways to override `auth.gsp`. By creating manually Controller and gsp or by using `spring-security-ui` plugin.

I have used second way to generate custom login page:

First, We need to add Spring Security Core Plugin as a dependency:
`/build.gradle`

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M1'
```

Use `s2-quickstart` to generate the default Spring Security Core domain classes:

```
grails s2-quickstart demo User Role
```

`s2-quickstart` script generates three domain classes; `User`, `Role` and `UserRole`.

Then install `Grails spring-security-ui plugin` from [here](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-ui)

use `grails s2ui-override auth` command to override the `login/auth.gsp` form (this will create the login form so that you override it).
Note: This command will not create controller. It create `view` at path `login/auth.gsp`

[image]

Use `grails s2ui-override` layout to override the layouts for the form(this will create the `springSecurityUI.gsp` layout so that you override it)

[image]

References: [enter link description here](http://guides.grails.org/grails-spring-security-core-plugin-custom-authentication/guide/index.html)

**Note**: Please check plugin documentation as per your grails version.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

> Must I run another command to generate it (and the controller)?

No.  You could if you wanted to but you could also write the files yourself if you prefer.  If you want to generate them, the `spring-security-ui` plugin can help with that.  See https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ui/latest/index.html#customization for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I added "compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.2'" to my build script and run "s2ui-override auth", but I get the error "Command [s2ui-override] error: class path resource [login/auth.gsp] cannot be opened because it does not exist"